# Connect jersey client to JIRA REST api with oAuth

Tags: rest, oauth, jersey, jira

I want to make REST calls to JIRA with jersey client. I want to go through oAuth. Does anybody has sample code for that. I tried following documentation but it is very confusing for me.

```
ConsumerCredentials consumerCredentials = new ConsumerCredentials("hardcoded-consumer", "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAxZDzGUGk6rElyPm0iOua0lWg84nOlhQN1gmTFTIu5WFyQFHZF6OA4HX7xATttQZ6N21yKMakuNdRvEudyN/coUqe89r3Ae+rkEIn4tCxGpJWX205xVF3Cgsn8ICj6dLUFQPiWXouoZ7HG0sPKhCLXXOvUXmekivtyx4bxVFD9Zy4SQ7IHTx0V0pZYGc6r1gF0LqRmGVQDaQSbivigH4mlVwoAO9Tfccf+V00hYuSvntU+B1ZygMw2rAFLezJmnftTxPuehqWu9xS5NVsPsWgBL7LOi3oY8lhzOYjbMKDWM6zUtpOmWJA52cVJW6zwxCxE28/592IARxlJcq14tjwYwIDAQAB");
AccessToken accessToken = new AccessToken("Token", "Secrete");
        Feature feature = OAuth1ClientSupport.builder(consumerCredentials)
                .feature()
                .accessToken(accessToken)
                .build();


        Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
                .register(feature)
                .build();

        Response resp =
                client.target("http://jira.company.com/rest/api/2/project")
                    .request()
                    .get();

        System.out.println(resp.readEntity(String.class));
```

This is what i have right now. I got `oauth_problem=signature_method_rejected` as Error

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Twitter example](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/2.23.2/examples/oauth-client-twitter/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/examples/oauth/twitterclient/App.java) referenced in the documentation which you can use. Also are you utilizing `OAuth1AuthorizationFlow`? Based on the [documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/security.html#d0e12588) it is something you should use, and the twitter example also uses it.

Do you need to stick with plain Jersey? There is a library called [jira-rest-java-client](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.atlassian.jira.jira-rest-java-client/server/overview) that you could use for this:

- [Using Oauth and the Jira Java Rest Client](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/263719/using-oauth-and-the-jira-java-rest-client)
- [JIRA REST API Example - OAuth authentication](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-oauth-authentication)